# ¿Cómo puedo agregar la función de pedir permiso para descargar un archivo?

Tags: flutter, dart

Soy nuevo en flutter y estaba probando con este codigo, puedo descargar, pero me descarga directamente, quisiera poder agregar una funcion de que pida el permiso antes, quería saber si me podrian explicar o mostrar un ejemplo o proporcionarme un ejemplo, ya mire la documentación de permission_handler, pero no logro entenderla de todo al momento de estructurar el codigo.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late final _platform;
  String? _fileFullPath;
  bool _isLoading = false;
  late String progress;
  final urlPdf = "https://eqpro.es/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Ejemplo.pdf";

  Dio? dio;
  @override
  void initState() {
    dio = Dio();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<List<Directory>?> _getExternalStoragePath() async {
    return p.getExternalStorageDirectories(type: p.StorageDirectory.documents);
  }

  Future _dowbloadAndSaveFileToStorage(
      BuildContext context, String urlPath, String fileName) async {
    // ProgressDialog pr;
    // pr = new ProgressDialog(context, type: ProgressDialogType.Normal);
    // pr.style(message: "Download File...");

    try {
      //Show dialog
      // await pr.show();
      final dirList = await _getExternalStoragePath();
      final path = dirList![0].path;
      final file = File('$path/$fileName');
      await dio!.download(urlPath, file.path, onReceiveProgress: (rec, total) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = true;
          progress = ((rec / total) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%";
          print(progress);

          //update dialog

          // pr.update(message: "Please wait: $progress");https://eqpro.es/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/Ejemplo.pdf
        });
      });
      // pr.hide();
      _fileFullPath = file.path;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

existe un permiso para acceder al almacenamiento de tu dispositivo y los tienes que ubicar en `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Ahora si lo que quieres hacer es mostrar una alerta antes de que el usuario vaya a descargar el archivo, podría crear un `AlertDialog` antes de que ejecute la función de descargar:

```
showDialog(
            barrierDismissible: false,
            context: (context),
            builder: (builder) {
              return AlertDialog(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                ),
                title: Text('Descargar archivo.'),
                content: Text('¿Desea descargar el archivo correspondiente?'),
                actions: [
                  // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                  FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                         _dowbloadAndSaveFileToStorage(
  context, link, nombre)
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Si',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(82, 120, 187, 10),
                        ),
                      )),
       
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                    child: Text(
                      'No',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(82, 120, 187, 10),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            });
```

Tambien podrías jugar con SharedPreferences para que este cuadro de dialogo solo se presente una sola vez, espero y te haya servido.